# Potential operator for a particle in space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, potential

Considering a particle in 3d, the corresponding Hilbert space $H$ is the tensor product of individual Hilbert spaces

$H=(H_x \otimes   H_y \otimes  H_z)$

If the particle is in a potential $V(x,y,z)$ ,what is the corresponding potential operator for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V(x,y,z)$ has a development as a series in $x,y,z$, then the potential operator $\hat V$ is obtained by replacing $x,y,z$ in the series by the corresponding operators $\hat x \otimes 1 \otimes 1, 1\otimes \hat y \otimes 1$ and $1\otimes 1 \otimes \hat z$.

Comment: $f (x, y)  = f (a, b) + f_x(a, b) (x - a) $ what do I replace f(a,b) by?

Comment: This constant times the identity operator.

Comment: Thank you......